# HttpURLConnection returns 404 status code when the same URL works on Browser

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I'm sending a GET request to a URL in a for loop with changing one parameter from java code. Now my request is working fine for 5-6 times but after a certain point the status code for my connection becomes 404 and all the way down from that point my requests are failing. but when I try to connect to the URL from browser with following the sites direction(clicking the buttons that gets me to the same url) it works without any problem.

Here is the function I'm using for Httpconnection:

```
private static void getFile(String name) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
    String url = "http://<this is not showed>"+URLEncoder.encode(name.trim(),"UTF-8")+".mp3";
    URL obj = new URL (url);
        try {
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.connect();
            //saving the file returned from request
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/audios/"+name+".mp3"));
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;

            while((len1 = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }

            fileOutputStream.close();
            connection.disconnect();
            break;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

and here is the part where I'm using the `getFile` funciton:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            getFile(names[i]);
}
```

Here is the output of the loop:

```
HTML connection status: 200
a| File downloaded succesfully.
HTML connection status: 200
 ab| File downloaded succesfully.
HTML connection status: 200
 ba| File downloaded succesfully.
HTML connection status: 200
 dî| File downloaded succesfully.
HTML connection status: 200
 jur| File downloaded succesfully.
HTML connection status: 200
 küs| File downloaded succesfully.
HTML connection status: 200
 ban| File downloaded succesfully.
HTML connection status: 404
java.io.FileNotFoundException:
```

and it keeps like that.

Comment: What happens when you run in debug mode.Add loggers and try to check for any exception condition

Comment: May be the url you are connecting does not allow many requests at same time.

Comment: I did debug it , the URL is returning 404. And as you say there is something about my request that I need to configure like whatever the browser doing And by the way I did use the URL in the browser like 20-25 times over and over again but it worked fine so I don't think its about the number of requests.

Comment: And I'm waiting 3 seconds in the for loop between each request.